# Range.Value not working for assigning cell contents to variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am writing my first script with VBA and I am having a hard time assigning the value entered into a cell to a String variable, I used Message Boxes to test where the issue is and it showed me I'm in the right workbook and the right sheet but then shows a blank for the value in "A1" even though I have a text value there and made sure I saved the workbook, what I have is below:

```
Sub copyworksheet()

Dim sourceWorkbook As String 
Dim destinationWorkbook As String 

Dim folderName As String

destinationWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Sheets(1).Activate

MsgBox Range("A1").Value        ' Shows blank when debugging
folderName = Range("A1").Value
MsgBox "Here is " & folderName  ' Shows "Here is " when debugging

End Sub
```

** As an additional note, the A1 cell contains 02Nov, and I have tried changing the format of this cell and it hasn't fixed the issue, currently the cell format is Text

Comment: The above code is working fine and proper? I think there is another workbook activated?

Comment: 1. makes sure that you are refering to the correct sheet: `Sheets(1)` refers to the first tab whether it be a worksheet, code sheet or chart sheet.  May be better to refer to it by name: `Worksheets("Sheet1")`  2.  Get rid of the activate; Use : `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` to fully qualify your range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
Sub copyworksheet()

Dim sourceWorkbook As String 
Dim destinationWorkbook As String 
Dim folderName As String

destinationWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

MsgBox Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value      'reference the Sheet absolutely when using Range  
folderName = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
MsgBox "Here is " & folderName  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is using `Cells`.

```
MsgBox Cells(1, 1).Value
folderName = Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Sheets(1)`

refers to the first tab in the active workbook.  That tab can be a worksheet, code sheet or chart sheet.

It is better to use `WorkSheets()` to reference worksheets. To ensure that you always get the correct sheet, regardless of order, use the name:

```
WorkSheets("Sheet1")
```

The best method would be to use the `CodeName`.  This is the name of the sheet that the user cannot change.  It is found in the sheet list in VBA:

[image]

The part before the `()` is the `Codename`.  So `Worksheets("Sheet1")` Code Name is `Sheet1`.  Using the code name we reference the sheet simply by typing it:

```
Sheet1
```

This cannot be easily changed by the user, as the name of the sheet can.  This will always refer to the proper sheet regardless of tab position and name of the sheet.

Next:

Do not use `.Activate` or `.Select`  They just slow down the code.  Just append the ranges with the correct sheet references:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Or better with the `CodeName`:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1")
```